# Lync Client SDK 2013 : Skype for Business File Attachement

Tags: wpf, skype-for-business, lync-client-sdk

I'm trying to log the file name when attaching the file in skype for business by using Lync Client SDK 2013.
I used the ContentSharingModality's ModalityStateChanged and ContentAdded event.

My problem is that this ContentSharingModality's event only raised successfully on a online meeting
but this cannot raised when normal IM,Audio/Video Call.
Could you advice the best solve of my problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content sharing is a feature of the conference server so it's only available in meeting conversations.  It's not available in one-to-one conversations.

As soon as you add content in the Lync Client UI your conversation is auto-upgraded to a meeting conversation.  If your using the Lync Client SDK you have to upgrade the conversation in code before you can start to use the ContentSharingModality or you have to detect the conversation being converted to a meeting conversation before you can use the ContentSharingModality.